# ClassNotFoundException when running newest version of stanford-postagger 3.6.0

Tags: stanford-nlp

I found the Stanford pos tagger and would like to use it in a project I am working on. 
Unfortunately, I get the following error when I try to run it:

> Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.(IOUtils.java:41)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:765)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.(MaxentTagger.java:298)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.(MaxentTagger.java:263)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTaggerGUI$1.run(MaxentTaggerGUI.java:89)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           ... 5 more

The same error occurred whether running within eclipse, command line, or gui.

I discovered after searching for a solution and trying many that didn't help, that the previous version 3.5.2 runs just fine with no errors so I will revert to the previous version for now.

Is it possible there is a problem with the new version?

Comment: Are you including all the jar files shipped with Stanford CoreNLP? There are quite a few in the binary download. All of these need to be on your classpath. (Looks like you are probably missing the `sl4j` jar here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've added slf4j logging to our releases.  In 3.6.0 there is a folder called lib which needs to be added to the CLASSPATH.